# Преобразование Dataframe на основе значений двух столбцов

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, multidex

Имеется Dataframe res вида:

[image: Dataframe res]

Код для создания DataFrame:

```
data = {'GP':[1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,3,3,2], 'Year': [2020,2021,2022,2023,2020,2021,2022,2023,2020,2021,2022,2023], 'g_bot':[1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,3,3,2], 'g_ham':[1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,3,3,2], 'g_tal':[1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,3,3,2]}
res = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

Необходимо получить res_total таблицу, группирующую значения по уровням
GP 1-> g_bot, g_ham, g_tal -> сумма значений, GP 2-> g_bot, g_ham, g_tal -> сумма значений, GP 3-> g_bot, g_ham, g_tal -> сумма значений, в качестве индекса столбец Year
такого вида:

### [image: Dataframe res_total]

---

Используя `res = res.pivot_table(index='Year', columns='GP', values= ['g_bot', 'g_ham', 'g_tal'],aggfunc='sum')`
Я получил следующий результат:

---

[image: res_user]

---

Как мне получить Dataframe необходимого вида(res_total)? Нужно указать другие аргументы в `pivot_table`или же выполнить перегруппирование столбцов в получившейся таблице res?

Comment: можете выложить данные для DataFrame в виде Знерщт кода или CSV? Вбивать  данные с картинки не очень хочется

Comment: @MaxU конечно, пардон ```res = {'GP':[1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,3,3,2],
        'Year': [2020,2021,2022,2023,2020,2021,2022,2023,2020,2021,2022,2023],
        'g_bot':[1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,3,3,2],
        'g_ham':[1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,3,3,2],
        'g_tal':[1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,3,3,2]}```

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените все картинки в вопросе данными в текстовом виде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.swaplevel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) и [DataFrame.sort_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
r = (res
     .pivot_table(index='Year', columns='GP', 
                  values=['g_bot', 'g_ham', 'g_tal'], 
                  aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
     .swaplevel(axis=1)
     .sort_index(axis=1))
```

результат:

```
In [15]: r
Out[15]:
GP       1                 2                 3
     g_bot g_ham g_tal g_bot g_ham g_tal g_bot g_ham g_tal
Year
2020     2     2     2     0     0     0     3     3     3
2021     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
2022     0     0     0     2     2     2     6     6     6
2023     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
```